# DataTables - Filter data in a set of values

Tags: mysql, datatables

**Hello everyone**, I am using the jQuery '`DataTables`' plugin to **page and sort** resulting to a query MySQL client-side data and emerged me a doubt.

Is it possible to **filter** the data via a  or something?

I have a tuple whose content ranges from 1 to 5 and would like to filter by this data, via a **dropdown** that I contain the range of values that can occur, as do for example with the name or age of a person through the column headings.

I hope I explained well, **greetings and thank** you very much everyone.

Adittional info:

Like this https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html but instead of a range with an input of type SELECT - OPTION with numbers from 0 to 5, according to the selected number display tuples whose field is the selected number.

Comment: please elaborate with example..

Comment: Adittional info in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Individual column searching (select inputs)](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) example on DataTables website.

You can also modify the JavaScript code in the example to display filter drop-down for particular columns only.